# HP Proliant Gen 8 moving from Windows 7 to Ubuntu Server 19.10 RAID Issues

Tags: ubuntu, hp, hp-proliant

I have been running Windows 7 on an HP Proliant Microserver Gen 8 for a good few years now, and as end of life comes closer I have decided to move to Linux.

I have 4 drives, two of which are in a RAID 1 array.

How would I rebuild this RAID 1 array to use in Ubuntu, as it is currently showing up as two drives, but with the same UUID.

I have looked at mdadm but as I'm not very experienced with RAID I didn't want to do anything that could lose my data.

I have mounted the other disks and they mount fine.

Any comments are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What kind of RAID 1 setup did you use in windows? Hardware RAID? Then per my guess it should also work in Ubuntu. If it doesn't, it's best to set up LVM with RAID1. Here's a guide:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/RAID1%2BLVM

Be sure to backup your data first

Comment: I believe it was fakeraid using the HP b160i controller built in. I can't find any ubuntu drivers for this card.

Comment: fakeraid is raid via your BIOS, there are no extra drivers involved. It's also not a recommended way to do RAID, so I recommend you look into real linux RAID technologies like mdraid/lvm, btrfs or zfs